# Как разбить значения-списки CSV на строки, используя разделитель?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, анализ-данных

Условно есть DataFrame:

```
А   Б
1 | 2,3 
2 | 3,5 
3 | 8,9
```

В котором значение CSV из столбца Б надо разбить по строкам используя разделитель, чтобы получилось такое:

```
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 3
2 | 5
3 | 8
3 | 9
```

Comment: У вас все-таки не список во столбце "Б", а строка. Это надо иметь в виду.

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам подошёл, а то этот вопрос всплывает как неотвеченный на сайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методами [Series.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) и [Series.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode)

Пример:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   val
1  2,3
2  3,5
3  8,9

In [64]: res = df["val"].str.split(",").explode()

In [65]: res
Out[65]:
1    2
1    3
2    3
2    5
3    8
3    9
Name: val, dtype: object
```